# Jmeter - Batch file creation for reports dashboard

Tags: batch-file, jmeter

I need to run the following command:

```bat
jmeter -g /path/to/jtl/file -o /where/you/want/to/store/dashboard
```

Requirement: There is a folder which has many jtl extension files. the above `jmeter` command creates a dashboard for jtl file. I need a batch script that would create a folder for each jtl file and when i run the above `jmeter` file it should take in each jtl file and create a dashboard. Currently folder gets created and dashboard is loaded only for the first jtl file.

jtl files location: `C:\Jmeter\Tests`. It has files like `test01.jtl`,`test02.jtl`...
Dashboard to be created at `C:\Jmeter\Dashboard` - here folder called `Test01` , `Test02` ... needs to be created.

When I run `jmeter -g C:\Jmeter\Tests\Test01.jtl -o  C:\Jmeter\Dashboard\Test01\`
through the script, it only creates a dashboard for `Test01` and not for the rest of the files.

```bat
@echo off

set hh=%time:~-11,2%
set /a hh=%hh%+100
set hh=%hh:~1%
set dateseed=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%hh%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
set dashboardPath=C:\Jmeter\Dashboard
set folderpath=C:\Jmeter\Tests

if not exist "%dashboardPath%\%dateseed%" mkdir "%dashboardPath%\%dateseed%"
set folder=%dashboardPath%\%dateseed%

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd %folderpath%

for %%A in (*.jtl) do (
    echo file found  %%A
    for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set fname=%%~nB
    for /f "delims=" %%C in ("%%A") do set fextn=%%~xC
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%D in ("!fname!") do set folname=%folder%\%%D

    echo folder name !folname!
    cd %folder%
    if not exist "!folname!" (
        echo Folder !folname! does not exist, creating
        md "!folname!"
        cd C:\Jmeter1\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin
        jmeter -g "%folderpath%\%%A" -o "!folname!"
    ) else (
        echo Folder !folname! exists
    )
)

pause
```

Output:
[image]

Output folder looks like below:
[image]

Comment: The variable `fname` is never defined.  The three nested `FOR` commands are pointless.  You can use the `%%A` variable directly to do the same thing. I have no idea what you are trying to do wit this code: **set fna`enter code here`me=**

Comment: This line of code will fail if the hour is 08 or 09 because it will be seen as an Octal. `set /a hh=%hh%+100`

Comment: Nice catch Squashman.  A good fix for that would be to combine it with the line before into `set hh=1%time::=&rem;%` (assuming the delimiter in rajee's locale for HH:MM:SS is a colon).

Comment: You also need to provide real world examples of your file names.  I can see a possible issue if the base file name before the underscore is the same on multiple files.

Comment: Have updated the requirement, didn't paste the code properly previously. hope its more clear now. the time stamp is just to have a unique folder..

Comment: tried this..... now         @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set dashboardPath=C:\Jmeter\Dashboard
set folderpath=C:\Jmeter\Tests

cd %folderpath%

for %%i in (*.jtl) do mkdir %dashboardPath%\%%~ni

for %%A in (*.jtl) do (
for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set fname=%%~nB
pause
echo source %folderpath%\%%A 
echo desti %dashboardPath%\%%~nB !fname!
pause
cd C:\Jmeter1\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin
jmeter -g "%folderpath%\%%A" -o "%dashboardPath%\!fname!"
   )
   pause
'
three folders created Test01 with correct data, test02 empty and !fname! which has the data of Test02

Comment: The `for` loop is iterating in the current directory for `*.jtl` files. Use of `cd` changes the current directory in the `for` loop. The 2nd file to be iterated does not exist in the new current directory so the `for` loop ends. If you need to `cd` in the `for` loop, then instead use `pushd` to change and `popd` to reset with each iteration.

Comment: @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set dashboardPath=C:\Jmeter\Dashboard
set folderpath=C:\Jmeter\Tests

cd %folderpath%

for %%A in (*.jtl) do (
mkdir %dashboardPath%\%%~nA
for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do ( set fname=%%~nB
pause
pushd C:\Jmeter1\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin
jmeter -g "%folderpath%\%%A" -o "%dashboardPath%\!fname!"
popd
   )   )
   pause

Comment: @michael_heath thanks for the reply, used pushd and popd, looks like Test01 is populated correctly but still test02 is empty but a folder with !fname! has been created , which has the reports for Test02.... have pasted the code above in the comments, sorry for som reason couldnt format it

Comment: Comments are not suitable for posting multi-line code so better to update your question with the code instead. I do not know how to reproduce the actual folder name creation of `!fname!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set dashboardPath=C:\Jmeter\Dashboard
set folderpath=C:\Jmeter\Tests

cd %folderpath%

for %%i in (*.jtl) do mkdir %dashboardPath%\%%~ni
for %%A in (*.jtl) do (
for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set fname=%%~nB
pushd C:\Jmeter1\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin
start jmeter -g "%folderpath%\%%A" -o "%dashboardPath%\!fname!"
popd
   )
```

All it needed was start at the beginning of the jmeter run command

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "dashboardPath=C:\Jmeter\Dashboard"
set "folderpath=C:\Jmeter\Tests"

cd /d "%folderpath%"

for %%A in (*.jtl) do (
    if not exist "%dashboardPath%\%%~nA" mkdir "%dashboardPath%\%%~nA"
    set "fname=%%~nA"
    pushd "C:\Jmeter1\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin" && (
        jmeter -g "%folderpath%\%%~nxA" -o "%dashboardPath%\!fname!"
        popd
    )
)
pause
```

**Example 1.**

Uses the `pushd` and `popd` to change directory to run `jmeter`.
Uses delayed expansion for `fname`.
These commands are perhaps not needed so will display an alternative.

---

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "dashboardPath=C:\Jmeter\Dashboard"
set "folderpath=C:\Jmeter\Tests"
set "path=%path%;C:\Jmeter1\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin"

cd /d "%folderpath%"

for %%A in (*.jtl) do (
    if not exist "%dashboardPath%\%%~nA" mkdir "%dashboardPath%\%%~nA"
    jmeter -g "%folderpath%\%%~nxA" -o "%dashboardPath%\%%~nA"
)

pause
```

**Example 2.**

Adds `jmeter` path to the `path` variable so change directory not needed.
No delayed expansion as `%%~nA` is used instead of setting to `fname`.

---

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "hh=%time:~,2%"
set "hh=%hh: =0%"
set "dateseed=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%hh%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%"
set "dashboardPath=C:\Jmeter\Dashboard"
set "folderpath=C:\Jmeter\Tests"
set "path=%path%;C:\Jmeter1\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin"

cd /d "%folderpath%"

for %%A in (*.jtl) do (
    if not exist "%dashboardPath%\%dateseed%\%%~nA" mkdir "%dashboardPath%\%dateseed%\%%~nA"
    jmeter -g "%folderpath%\%%~nxA" -o "%dashboardPath%\%dateseed%\%%~nA"
)

pause
```

**Example 3.**

Like the 2nd code though using the `dateseed` concept.
The time may start with a space if hour is a single digit,
so using variable substitution of `%hh: =0%` which replaces
any space with a zero.

Not sure exactly what suits your requirements, so have offered a few examples.

Comment: Thank you so much @michael_heath, that helped a lot.